# (Visual) intuition behind the geometric multiplicity of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I computed the eigenvalues- and spaces for the following 3x3 matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 4&2&3 \\
-1 & 1 & -3\\
 2 & 4 & 9\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The eigenvalue 3 has an algebraic multiplicity of 2, so its geometric multiplicity can be 1 or 2. In fact, its geometric multiplicity is indeed 2 as the eigenspace is spanned by the vectors
$\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ ,
$\begin{pmatrix}-3 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$.
Calculating all this stuff is easy for me, I just can't wrap my head around what I'm supposed to do with the information I gain from the geometric multiplicity. What's the difference between a geometric multiplicity of 1 and 2 in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Does the geometric multiplicity of 2 in my case just mean that all eigenvectors associated with my eigenvalue of 3 lie in a plane instead of on a line?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Asserting that the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $3$ is $2$ means that the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $3$ is $2$. So, that eigenspace is a plane passing through the origin. If the geometric multiplicity was $1$, then the eigenspace would be a line passing through the origin.

Comment: Not sure this is correct. Algebraic multiplicity has obvious meaning - it refers to multiplicity of the root. Now - 3 is eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity 2. But we do not know if there are 2 (independent) eigenvectors corresponding to this value. We know there is one. The other one can be (must be in fact) in the eigenspace corresponding to 3 i.e. $(A-3I)^2 x_2 = 0$ but $(A-3I)x_2 != 0$

Comment: @Salcio What I wrote was about the *geometric* multiplicity. I did not even mention the *algebraic* multiplicity.